# Triple buffering using OpenGL on IOS

Tags: ios, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

Our app still uses OpenGLES2.0 on IOS. Yes, I know we should use Metal, but our app also works on Android. While most of the time it runs perfectly happy on 60 fps, occasionally there's a glitch, and in come cases it seems to alternate between taking one frame to render the scene, then two frames. 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2... Then, without changing whats rendered, it will jump back to 1,1,1 i.e. 60fps.  The delay is in the first glClear after we've 'presented' the last buffer.  I guess OpenGL is either still rendering the last scene, and it has to wait a whole frame to sync up again. Maybe our render/update loop takes close to or just over a whole frame - this would help explain the delay, as it 'misses' the vsync.

However, If we had triple buffering I would expect the frame times to be 1,1,2, 1,1,2, 1,1,2.. not 1,2,1,2,1,2,1.  Is there a way to get the IOS to use triple buffering ?

Currently we only seem to initialise two 'buffers'

```
GLuint viewRenderbuffer;
GLuint viewFramebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
```

Then we call this after each frame is finished rendering

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Normally I would expect to call glSwapbuffers somewhere, but I expect that is inside the presentRenderbuffer call. I guess it's up to the driver then to handle double or triple buffering.

Is there a way to force triple buffering, or is this actually already being used.

Thanks
Shaun

Comment: More investigation using the profiler shows interesting results.

When the game is running smoothly, the GPU is busy for just under a frame, and three surfaces, 14,15,16, are cycled in order. Looks like triple buffering to me.

When it starts juddering, there are big stalls "waiting for a free surface", and the order of displayed surfaces is something like 14 (1 frame) 15 (3 frames) 14 (1 frame) 16 (3 frames)..  It can get back in sync, but I have no idea how this happens.  If I put a glFinish at the end of the render it slows down but is consistently slow.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering on iOS is tripple buffered by default. This prevents frame tearing/and or stalls. Frame stuttering usually occurs when your avarage frame time is bigger than the limit imposed by the vsync interval (e.g. ~16.6ms for 60 FPS). You can check this time in XCode profiling tools or measure it yourself using system timers and draw the result in a debug HUD.

Unexpected performance drops with the same rendered contect could be due to CPU/GPU frequency managment by the OS.

Please check out this talk about Frame Pacing (6:00 and onwards)
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/612/

On a side note, performance may be bad not only because of raw load, but also synchronization issues. An example of a synchronization issue is reading back framebuffer content or improper handling of dynamic vertex/index buffers.

Improving rendering performance on mobile is a complex issue involving carefull handling of FBOs to avoid unnecessary bandwidth usage. You can use XCode profiling tools & frame capture to find the bottleneck.